# Getting an error when trying to start glassfish 4 in linux

Tags: java, linux, glassfish

I am new to Linux and glassfish and recently i got an assignment to upgrade one of the apps which used Tomcat to a new version which uses glassfish. To achieve this i installed glassfish using the instructions mentioned in the guide but when i am trying to start glassfish using the command glassfish4/bin/asadmin start-domain, i am getting the below error:

[image]

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Your JDK may be too old for this version of Glassfish .

Comment: I am using JDK 8, jdk-8u77-linux-x64.tar.gz was the file name that i installed in the server

Comment: Can it be a port issue as the default port for glassfish is 8080 and my tomcat is also running on the same port

Comment: I don't think that you would have the same error, you would probably get a BindException. However, you really should change the port.

Comment: can you guide me how to change the port